# Come si chiama la giacca che si mette dopo la doccia

Tags: nouns

C'è un tipo di giacca fatta come un telo, che mettiamo per un ora dopo la doccia per farci asciugare, prima che indossiamo i vestiti, però ha un nome difficile e non riesco trovarlo su internet neanche.

Comment: In inglese è *bathrobe*

Answer (score 7):

Si chiama accappatoio. Qui trovi la definizione da dizionario: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/accappatoio/ .

[image]

Comment: Penso che la parola del dizionario Treccani e quella che hai scritto prima sia la stessa: è soltanto una questione di scrivere o no l'accento grafico. Il dizionario lo fa per rendere più chiara la pronuncia.  Un'altra cosa: potresti aggiungere il link al dizionario?

Comment: In realtà avevo aggiunto quella parte solo per raggiungere i 30 caratteri. Adesso ho corretto aggiungendo il link al dizionario.

Comment: Grazie, @Matte.Car!

Comment: Grazie mille, ma posso chiedere cosa vuol dire basandosi sulla treccani?

Comment: Treccani è uno dei principali dizionari di italiano.

Comment: @Matte.Car Ho cambiato l'immagine con una liberamente disponibile (e senza marchio aziendale) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/PinkBathrobe.JPG/386px-PinkBathrobe.JPG

Comment: Hai fatto bene, non ci avevo pensato.

Comment: Grazie mille tutti

Comment: Prego. Se ritieni la mia risposta corretta, dovresti marcarla come tale.